# How To add custom radio boxes to WooCommerce Billing page and change total price by this field?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

Lets say i need to add custom radio fields ( company or person )  at the top of the form to the billing for. And if the visitor checks person they should pay 21% Tax and they select company that is localated in NL they also should pay 21% tax. Any other case they should be free of tax? Any ideas ?

This is what i've tried :

```
add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_billing_fields');
```

function custom_woocommerce_billing_fields($fields){

```
$fields['customer_type'] = array(
    'label' => __('Bedrijf', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder' => _x('Bedrijf', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required' => false,
    'clear' => false,
    'type' => 'checkbox',
    'class' => array('my-css'),
);

$fields['customer_type_personal'] = array(
    'label' => __('Persoonlijke', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder' => _x('Persoonlijke', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required' => false,
    'clear' => false,
    'type' => 'checkbox',
    'class' => array('my-css-2'),
);

return $fields;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_billing_fields');

function custom_woocommerce_billing_fields($fields)
{

    $fields['billing_options'] = array(
        'label' => __('Ordering Method', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field label
        'placeholder' => _x('Your NIF here....', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field placeholder
        'required' => true, // if field is required or not
        'clear' => false, // add clear or not
        'type' => 'radio', // add field type
        'class' => array('form-group'),    // add class name
        'options'         => array(
        'privato_cittadino'         => 'Privato cittadino',
        'azienda_professionista'    => 'Azienda o libero professionista',
      ),

    );
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

To add the custom radio fields to the billing form, you can use the `woocommerce_form_field()` function in the `woocommerce_billing_fields` filter hook.

Here is an example:

```
function custom_woocommerce_billing_fields($fields) {
    $fields['customer_type'] = array(
        'label' => __('Bedrijf', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder' => _x('Bedrijf', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'required' => false,
        'clear' => false,
        'type' => 'radio',
        'class' => array('my-css'),
        'options' => array(
            'company' => __('Company', 'woocommerce'),
            'person' => __('Person', 'woocommerce'),
        ),
    );

    return $fields;
}
```

This will add a radio field with two options: "Company" and "Person". The `woocommerce_form_field()` function will automatically render the field as a set of radio buttons.

To apply the tax based on the selected option, you can use the `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` hook. This hook is called before the cart totals are calculated, so you can use it to modify the tax rate based on the selected customer type.

Here is an example:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'custom_before_calculate_totals');
function custom_before_calculate_totals($cart) {
    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX'))
        return;

    if (did_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals') >= 2)
        return;

    // Get the selected customer type
    $customer_type = isset($_POST['customer_type']) ? $_POST['customer_type'] : '';

    // Set the tax rate based on the selected customer type
    $tax_rate = 0;
    if ($customer_type == 'person') {
        $tax_rate = 0.21;
    } elseif ($customer_type == 'company') {
        $tax_rate = 0.21;
    }

    // Loop through each cart item and set the tax rate
    foreach ($cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        $cart_item['data']->set_tax_class($tax_rate);
    }
}
```

This code checks the selected customer type, and sets the tax rate based on the selected option. It then loops through each cart item and sets the tax class for each item to the calculated tax rate.